# Data doesn't display immediately after clicking a button.It takes manually refresh page again

Tags: apex, visualforce, batch, actionsupport, refresh

I tried a lot to resolving this issue but not able to achieving the requirement.Please help me on this

After Clicking a button in **Panel 1**,It navigates to **Panel 2** and Initially it displays **panel 2** as empty.after few seconds If i refresh **panel 2** It displays data.

Anyone suggest how can I display data immediately after clicking a button without refreshing a page again.

The below code works perfectly.No errors and all.But only the issue is data isn't visible immediately after clicking a button.

### **page:**

```
            --------------------------------------------Panel-1--------------------------------------------------

            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!flag1}">               
             <center>
                <apex:commandButton value="Assign Vouchers and Send Email" action="{!process}"   reRender="pg1" styleClass="slds-button slds-button_brand" />

             </center>               
             <center>
                 <b>Generate and Assign Voucher</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!checkBoxval}"></apex:inputCheckBox>
             </center>                       
          </apex:outputPanel>                                 
            --------------------------------------------Panel-2--------------------------------------------------
            <apex:outputPanel id="pg1" >
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!flag}" >

            <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer slds-no-row-hover" style="table-layout:fixed; width:100%">
             <thead>
                                <tr class="slds-text-title_caps slds-line-height_reset">
                                    <th scope="col">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Name</div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Email">Email</div>
                                    </th>                               
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <apex:repeat value="{!MyResult}" var="c" id="table"> 

                                    <tr>
                                        <td data-label="Name">
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" >{!c.Name}  </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td scope="row" data-label="Email">
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" >{!c.Login__c}</div>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </apex:repeat>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>

            Controller :
            --------------
            public with sharing class VoucherController{
            public PageReference process(){ 
                     if(checkBoxVal==true){
                       VoucherGenerate_AssignBatch b = new VoucherGenerate_AssignBatch();
                       Database.executeBatch(b);               
                       flag = true;  
                       flag1 = false ; 

                    }
                }
            }

            Batch Class:
            -------------
            global with sharing class VoucherGenerate_AssignBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {   
                global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

                    String query = 'SELECT Id,Login__c,Name,Priority__c,Opportunity__c,Opportunity__r.CloseDate, Attandance_Status__c,  WebinarContact__c,WebinarContact__r.Name,WebinarContact__r.Email,'+
                                   'Voucher_Number__c,Email_Sent__c  FROM Webinar_Attendees__c WHERE Opportunity__c != Null  AND Attandance_Status__c = \'Attended\' '; 
                    system.debug('query :: '+query);
                    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);         
                }

                global void execute (Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Webinar_Attendees__c> scope) {

                    integer limitCount;           
                    List<Webinar_Attendees__c> updateWebinarAttendees = new List<Webinar_Attendees__c>();    
                    Map<Id,List<Webinar_Attendees__c>> myl = new Map<Id,List<Webinar_Attendees__c>>(); 
                    Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();

                    Adobe_Connect__c c = [select id,Name,VouchersPerOpportunity__c,Days__c from Adobe_Connect__c];  
                    system.debug('VouchersPerOpportunity__c custom settings value :: ' +c.VouchersPerOpportunity__c);
                    system.debug('Days__c custom settings value::'+c.Days__c); 
                    if(c.VouchersPerOpportunity__c != Null){
                       limitCount = (Integer)c.VouchersPerOpportunity__c ;      
                    }else{ limitCount = 3; }
                    system.debug('limitCount value :: ' +limitCount) ;   

                    //Changed by pramineni: Fetching webinar attendees ordering by priority instead of createddate and making Priority with null attendees last
                    for(Webinar_Attendees__c wc : scope) {           
                        List<Webinar_Attendees__c> w = [SELECT Id,Login__c,Name,Opportunity__c,Priority__c,Attandance_Status__c,Opportunity__r.CloseDate,Opportunity__r.OppVoucherCount__c,  Webinar__r.IsDeleted__c,
                                                        Webinar__r.IsRestored__c,Webinar__r.Start_Time__c,Webinar__r.Name,WebinarContact__c,WebinarContact__r.Name,WebinarContact__r.Email,Voucher_Number__c,Email_Sent__c
                                                        FROM Webinar_Attendees__c WHERE Opportunity__c = : wc.Opportunity__c  AND Attandance_Status__c = 'Attended'   AND Voucher_Number__c = Null AND Email_Sent__c = false
                                                        ORDER BY Priority__c ASC NULLS LAST];               
                        myl.put(wc.Opportunity__c,w);     
                        system.debug('myl :: ' +myl) ;
                    }

                    for(Id oppId : myl.keySet()){

                        system.debug('oppId from Map :: '+oppId);
                        List<Webinar_Attendees__c> wlst = myl.get(oppId);
                        system.debug('wlst size from Map :: '+wlst.size());
                        system.debug('wlst from Map :: '+wlst);

                        if(wlst.size() > 0){ 

                            Opportunity opp = [SELECT Name,OppVoucherCount__c,StageName,CloseDate FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = : oppId];
                            Integer OppV_sum;
                            if(opp.OppVoucherCount__c == Null){
                                OppV_sum = 0;
                            }else{ OppV_sum = Integer.valueOf(opp.OppVoucherCount__c); }           

                            for(Webinar_Attendees__c wa : wlst){

                                system.debug('attendees webinar startDate'+wa.Webinar__r.Start_Time__c);
                                system.debug('opp close date'+opp.CloseDate);

                                //Changed by pramineni:: logic to check if the fair start date is less than 10 days to the webinar date then the attendee is not allowed a voucher
                                Integer i = wa.Webinar__r.Start_Time__c.date().daysBetween(opp.CloseDate);

                                system.debug('Difference:'+ i);
                                system.debug('OppV_sum value before :: '+OppV_sum);

                                if(i > c.Days__c) {                       
                                if((wa.Webinar__r.IsDeleted__c == false && wa.Webinar__r.IsRestored__c == true) || (wa.Webinar__r.IsDeleted__c == false && wa.Webinar__r.IsRestored__c == false )){

                                    if(OppV_sum < limitCount ){

                                        // if(wc.Voucher_Number__c == Null && wc.Email_Sent__c == false){  condition already present in query                   
                                        try{    
                                             Voucher_Repository__c v1 = new Voucher_Repository__c();
                                             v1.Voucher_Type__c = 'Online';
                                             DateTime dt = Datetime.now();
                                             v1.Voucher_StartDate__c = dt ;
                                             v1.Voucher_EndDate__c = dt.addDays(10);
                                             v1.Voucher_Value__c = 25 ;
                                             Insert v1;    

                                             Voucher_Repository__c v = [SELECT Id,Name,CheckAvailable__c,redeemed_On__c,redeemed_To__c,Voucher_EndDate__c,Voucher_StartDate__c,Voucher_Type__c,
                                                                        Voucher_Validity__c,Voucher_Value__c FROM Voucher_Repository__c WHERE Id = : v1.id];                                

                                             system.debug('New Voucher ::'+v);    
                                             String emailid = wa.Login__c;      //wa.WebinarContact__r.Email ;
                                             system.debug(' email is :: ' +emailid); 

                                            if(v != Null && emailid != Null){

                                                OppV_sum = OppV_sum + 1;
                                                system.debug('OppV_sum value After :: '+OppV_sum);   
                                                v.redeemed_To__c = wa.Id;  
                                                v.redeemed_On__c = wa.Opportunity__r.CloseDate;                                                                
                                                v.CheckAvailable__c = true ;                                            

                                                // Email processing
                                                EmailTemplate template = [select Id,Body,HtmlValue,Name,Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =  'MyTemplate2'];    // 'AlocateVoucherTemplate'];                                       
                                                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();                               
                                                String[] toAddresses = new String[] {emailid};   
                                                mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);  
                                                mail.setTemplateId(template.Id);
                                                mail.setSubject('Thanks for attending the '+wa.Webinar__r.Name+' Webinar');   
                                                mail.setReplyTo('XYZ@Salesforce.com'); //Set who the email is sent from
                                                mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce team');                                                               
                                                mail.setTargetObjectId(wa.WebinarContact__c);                               
                                                mail.setUseSignature(false);
                                                mail.setBccSender(false);
                                                mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);                                
                                                String plainBody = template.HtmlValue;   //htmlBody
                                                String ContactName;
                                                if(wa.WebinarContact__r.Name != Null ){
                                                   ContactName = wa.WebinarContact__r.Name;
                                                }else{
                                                   ContactName = wa.Name;
                                                }                                   
                                                plainBody = plainBody.replace('{!Contact.LastName}', ContactName);                               
                                                plainBody = plainBody.replace('{!Voucher_Name}', String.valueof(v.Name) );                                
                                                plainBody = plainBody.replace('{!Voucher_Value}', String.valueof(v.Voucher_Value__c) );                                
                                                Datetime d = v.redeemed_On__c ;                                                                      
                                                plainBody = plainBody.replace('{!redeemed_OnDate}', String.valueof(d.format('MM/dd/yyyy')));                             
                                                plainBody = plainBody.replace('{!Voucher_Validity}', String.valueof(v.Voucher_Validity__c));                               
                                                plainBody = plainBody.replace('{!Voucher_QrCode}',String.valueof(emailid+v.Name+'$'+v.Voucher_Value__c));                                       
                                                //mail.setPlainTextBody(plainBody);
                                                mail.setHTMLBody(plainBody);
                                                system.debug('email body :: ' + plainBody );   

                                                Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.SendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail}); 
                                                if (results[0].success) {
                                                    system.debug('The email was sent successfully.');
                                                    wa.Voucher_Number__c = v.Id;
                                                    wa.Email_Sent__c = true ;                                          
                                                }else{ system.debug('The email failed to send:'+ results[0].errors[0].message); }

                                                update v;
                                                updateWebinarAttendees.add(wa);

                                                if(OppV_sum > 0){
                                                    opp.OppVoucherCount__c = OppV_sum;
                                                    update opp;
                                                    system.debug('final value of opp.OppVoucherCount__c :: ' +opp.OppVoucherCount__c);
                                                }                                                                                           
                                            }else{                                                                  
                                               if(emailid == Null){ system.debug('** email value is blank **');  }                               
                                            }

                                        }catch(Exception e){  system.debug('Exception raised :: ' +e);   }                           

                                    }else { system.debug(' Opp voucher count is greater then Limit count '); }                                

                                }else { system.debug(' Webinar IsDeleted && Webinar IsRestored condition not met '); }                                      

                            }else { system.debug('The fair start date is less than 10 days to the webinar date');}
                          }                
                        }            
                    }  

                    update updateWebinarAttendees;  
                    system.debug('WebinarAttendees List updated :: ' + updateWebinarAttendees); 
                    system.debug('WebinarAttendees List updated size :: ' + updateWebinarAttendees.size());                       
                }
                global void finish(Database.BatchableContext batchableContext) {

                }   
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:commandButton value="Assign Vouchers and Send Email" action="{!process}"  styleClass="slds-button slds-button_brand" />
<apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="pg1" />
```

Here, you are rerendering `pg1` immediately on click. You should rerender after completing `action="{!process}"`. So, you should use `reRender` directly on `apex:commandButton`.

```
<apex:commandButton reRender="pg1" value="Assign Vouchers and Send Email" action="{!process}"  styleClass="slds-button slds-button_brand" />
```

---

```
<apex:outputPanel id="pg2" >
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!flag1}">               
         <center>
            <apex:commandButton value="Assign Vouchers and Send Email" action="{!process}"   reRender="pg1" styleClass="slds-button slds-button_brand" />

         </center>               
         <center>
             <b>Generate and Assign Voucher</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!checkBoxval}"></apex:inputCheckBox>
         </center>                       
      </apex:outputPanel> 
  </apex:outputPanel>
```

then rerender both: `reRender="pg1,pg2"`

Above will solve prob 1.

Now, for prob 2:

change apex method:

```
public PageReference process(){ 
    if(checkBoxVal==true){
        VoucherGenerate_AssignBatch b = new VoucherGenerate_AssignBatch();
        Database.executeBatch(b);               
        flag = true;  
        flag1 = false ; 

        String query = 'SELECT Id,Login__c,Name,Priority__c,Opportunity__c,Opportunity__r.CloseDate, Attandance_Status__c,  WebinarContact__c,WebinarContact__r.Name,WebinarContact__r.Email,'+
            'Voucher_Number__c,Email_Sent__c  FROM Webinar_Attendees__c WHERE Opportunity__c != Null  AND Attandance_Status__c = \'Attended\' '; 
        system.debug('query :: '+query);

        Myresult = Database.query(query);

    }
}
```

batch apex is async so those records will not be immediately available. You need to return direct soql query results

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97424/discussion-on-answer-by-salesforce-sas-data-doesnt-display-immediately-after-cl).

Comment: Stop posting comments here. Please use the chat for any continued discussion.